# Publishing Open Graph Action to Groups

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to be able to publish OG Actions to Facebook groups.  I am able to publish the action as follows:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/appfoundry:annotate 
{article: http://synchro.herokuapp.com/articles/10}
```

This works great, and the annotation shows up in my news feed.  But when I try to publish to one of my groups,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/305900672779368/appfoundry:annotate
{article: http://synchro.herokuapp.com/articles/10}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 240
  }
}
```

I would like these actions to be visible only in the groups, which might be private or secret, and I do NOT want them to show up in a user's news feed or ticker.

I am using the Graph API Explorer with my app selected, which has user_groups, publish_stream, publish_actions, share_item and status_update permissions.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Marty

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, only Users can publish Open Graph actions.

A user can choose who can see their actions, but can't currently only allow just members of a group to see those actions.